# Set minimum and maximum level of zoom

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm using cesium 3D map i

```
use var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;
var blackMarble = layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.IonImageryProvider({ assetId: 3812,  minimumLevel : 5 }));
```

i want to set minimum and maximum level of zoom used `minimumLevel : 5` but the earth size gets reduced

Link: https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/WebMapTileServiceImageryProvider.html

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Link: [working demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of the issue?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy: Added working demo link can you please check

Comment: Yea that's weird, even this is not working : `viewer.scene._screenSpaceCameraController.minimumZoomDistance = 5;` :/ I tried, sorry..

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy: No issue Alexandre, do you have any idea about capturing zoom out event i have to change the layer image on zoom out event

Answer (score 1):

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {});

viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.minimumZoomDistance = 6378137;
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.maximumZoomDistance = 6378137 * 2;
```